# Having trouble with user input in moving an image vertically

Tags: javascript, html, image, user-input

I need to move an image vertically by user input however, when I press the defined key nothing happens. I don't know if the command I am using to draw a new image going vertically is wrong or my function is?

**Script.js**

```
var map = document.getElementById("map");
var ctx = map.getContext("2d");

var baseImage = new Image();
baseImage.src = "assets/base.png";
baseImage.addEventListener("load", drawImage);

var speedyImage = new Image();
speedyImage.src = "assets/speedy.png";
speedyImage.addEventListener("load", drawImage);

var bubbleImage = new Image();
bubbleImage.src = "assets/bubble.png";
bubbleImage.addEventListener("load", drawImage);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){ handleKeyPress(event);});

var dt = 1000/30.0;

function intersectRect(r1, r2) { // detects collision

    return !(r2.left > r1.right ||
    r2.right < r1.left ||
    r2.top > r1.bottom ||
    r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function drawImage(){
    setInterval(update, 1000/30.0);
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var speed = 0.05;
var direction = 1;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = 0;

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, map.width, map.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            ctx.drawImage(bubbleImage,x, map.height - baseImage.height - 50);
            function handleKeyPress(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 32){ // if space
                                    // trouble here... would I just use the draw image function again?          

                }
            }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            ctx.drawImage(speedyImage,x,0);
            ctx.drawImage(speedyImage,x,70);
            ctx.drawImage(speedyImage,x,150);
        if(intersectRect(bubbleImage,speedyImage) == false)
            score+= score+100;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(baseImage, x, map.height - baseImage.height );
    y += speed*direction*dt;
    x += speed * direction * dt;    

    if (x > map.width - baseImage.width || x < 0)
        direction = -direction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `handlekeyPress(event)` function.

```
   for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        ctx.drawImage(bubbleImage,x, map.height - baseImage.height - 50);
        function handleKeyPress(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 32){ // if space
                                // trouble here... would I just use the draw image function again?          

            }
        }
}
```

As it is shown you are specifying function code inside another function .So this function cannot be called outside the function.

Comment: How would I declare the handkeyPress(event) function? Our teacher just barely taught us JS and told us to add the function but not how. Could you help me with this? Thank you and thank you for your input as well!